# How to set request header in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, get

Im doing a GET request on a webpage and it is not working because “No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource”, which I think means I need the header. How would I set this header on my site in my jquery.
My code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>Sample Page</title>
      <script>
     var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds=140239261",
       "method": "GET"
     }
         $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
           var content = response.data.playing;
           $("#counter").append(content);
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Sample Page</h1>
      <div id="counter">playing: </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for helping. I could not find a way to do this with jquery (atleast how my code is set up), so please help!
(Im a beginner in javascript so try to make the answer simple.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive this error,it actually means that you are trying to send request to a different domain than your page is on,based on your server side technology you should enable `CORS` on your server to accept request from other script that your server has not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds=140239261', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', // This alone should also work without the beforeSend below
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
                   xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                }
})
```

However, even this would only work if the server cross origin requests